Facing issue where i am unable to load the child.html in the index html with asciidoctor.jvm.convert 2.4.0
I am using spring docs 2.0.5 release version
I am using gradle 8.6, and i refer to this example to configure asciidoctor -i refered below link
        https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs-samples/blob/main/restful-notes-spring-hateoas/build.gradle

 test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  outputs.dir snippetsDir
   }

   asciidoctor {
      configurations "asciidoctorExtensions"
     inputs.dir snippetsDir
     dependsOn test

   doLast {
     copy{
       from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5")
      into "$buildDir/resources/main/public/docs")

      include "**/*.html"

    }

    I am getting below error when i try to load index.HTML.
    The public/docs folder has index.html,child.html,child1.html etc
   THe child.html,child1.html are referred inside the index.adoc

  i get below error on the console 
  Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::child.adoc[]
  Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::child1.adoc[]

   I tried changing the buildDir to project.layout as buildDir is deprecated in 8.6


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Follow this link - github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/issues/549 . Adding asciidoctor.baseDirFollowsSourceDir() in the asciidoctor task should fix the problem.
